# hide show div using Jquery ( reversal needed )

Tags: jquery

Please check out the fiddle:

[LINK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/de4FE/3/)

I would like to hide the DIV on page load, and use the ascii charater for up and down arrow on the LINK, so that onclick the div slides down . Works fine but I want the reverse functionality, so that it is hidden on page load. Have tried changing visibility to hidden, didnt work lol

Like:

Show ▼

and

Hide ▲

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just improved the code of Mr Andrew:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#setup").click(function() {
        $("#closeable").slideToggle(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                $("#setup").text("Hide Content ▲");
            }
            else {
                $("#setup").text("Show Content ▼");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/de4FE/26/

Comment: The issue I have is how do I display the $("#setup").text("Hide Content &#x25B2;"); Up and Down arrow pointer in the JS, without actually posting the image, as it states Character Encoding will be lost ?

Comment: For up use this \u25b2, for down use this \u25bc, [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/de4FE/43/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be invisible initially you could simply add `style="display:none"` to the `<div>` element.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#setup").click(function() {
        $("#closeable").slideToggle(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                $("#setup").text("Hide Content");
            }
            else {
                $("#setup").text("Show Content");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Make sure to check the visibility of the content in the callback function (to be sure that the content is visible).

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/de4FE/16/

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I tested, and this is what worked.

Note, that we add `$("#closeable").hide();` at the beginning of the ready() function, thus hiding our object div.

Second we move the `$("#closeable").slideToggle();` after the test. The problem you were experiencing was that `slideToggle()` executes as a thread and the rest of the code keeps executing, thus, it was still partially visible or just becoming visible for the `is(':visible')` statement. By testing first, we remove the race condition.

Cheers

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#closeable").hide();

    $("#setup").click(function() {

        if($("#closeable").is(":visible")) {
            $("#setup").text("Show Content ▼");
        }
        else {
            $("#setup").text("Hide Content ▲");
        }

        $("#closeable").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#closeable").slideToggle();
    state = "hide";

    $("#setup").click(function() {
        $("#closeable").slideToggle();

        if (state == "hide") {
            $("#setup").text("Show Content");
            state == "show"
        }
        else {
            $("#setup").text("Hide Content");
            state == "hide"
        }

    });
});
```